# JUnit4 - why does @Before run before @Test but not before @ParametrizedTest?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a JUnit 4 test class:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class MyBasicTest {

    boolean valueIsSetup = false;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        valueIsSetup = true;
    }

    @Test
    public void testUsingValue() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(valueIsSetup);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(booleans = {true, false})
    public void parametrizedUsingValue(boolean testValue) throws Exception {
        assertTrue(valueIsSetup);
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is a sample. This will fail in the `parametrizedUsingValue` test method.

`@BeforeClass` exists, but it requires the setup to be static and doesn't guarantee any cleanup of the static members you initialize. That can be a problem in actual tests, even though it would not be problem in the sample above.

Why does `@Before` not apply to `@ParametrizedTest`. Is there any way of working around that without compromising independence of tests?

Comment: I don't have a JUnit 4 handy to test, but I'm about 99% sure that `@Before` should work just fine with `@ParameterizedTest`. Are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else?

Comment: (i) is `ParameterizedTest` part of JUnit 4? (ii) [javadoc](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/) of `Before`: "Annotating a public void method with @Before causes that method to be run before the [Test](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html) method." (no `ParameterizedTest` mentioned/linked)

Comment: Any reason you use ParameterizedTest from junit 5 with junit 4?
Using `org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach` with `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;` is one of the way to fix the problem

Comment: [Parameterized tests in JUnit 4](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests) work vastly different from JUnit 5. You cannot use JUnit 5 annotations with JUnit 4 like you do in your question and expect it to work. Your test is probably run by a JUnit 5 runner, which doesn't do anything with `@Before` (the JUnit 5 equivalent is `@BeforeEach`).